# CGPath-based CPTPlotSymbol inverted and distorted

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm currently working with custom markers on a scatter plot and found myself with an issue that results in `CPTPlotSymbol` created from a `CGPath` upside down and distorted.

I've tested the path-creating code in a playground and it works without issues, drawing the path with the correct shape and orientation.

Here's the path drawing code:

```
private func getOuterPathInRect(rect: CGRect) -> CGPath {
    let circlePath: CGPath = {
        let p = CGMutablePath()
        let topHundred = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        p.addEllipse(in: topHundred)
        return p
    }()
    let arrowPath: CGPath = {
        let p = CGMutablePath()
        p.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY - 5.0))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - 7.5, y: rect.maxY - 15.0))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + 7.5, y: rect.maxY - 15.0))
        return p
    }()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addPath(circlePath)
    path.addPath(arrowPath)
    return path
}
```

And the code that creates the `CPTPlotSymbol` is:

```
func symbol(for plot: CPTScatterPlot, record idx: UInt) -> CPTPlotSymbol? {
    let index = Int(idx)
    guard items[index].requiresMarker else { return nil }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120)
    let marker = BallMarkerView()
    marker.contentMode = .center
    let path = marker.pathIn(rect: rect)
    let symbol = CPTPlotSymbol.customPlotSymbol(with: path)
    symbol.size = rect.size
    symbol.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.red())
    return symbol
}
```

My goal was to use a custom UIView as a marker, but I couldn't find an API to do so, so I resorted to providing a path-based marker and fill it with an image representation of the marker.

Is this the proper way of doing it?

Why is my path being drawn distorted and upside down? The path being upside down could be explained by the difference in the coordinate system between UIKit and CoreGraphics, but that doesn't explain the distorsion.

Thanks!

Comment: How is the symbol distorted? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, here's an image: http://imgur.com/a/nArcB

I have a custom `MarkerView` that exposes its outline as a `CGPath`.
I've taken that path and put it into a `CAShapeLayer` and added that to the live view of a playground, creating the black marker.

The red marker is the same path applied to a `CPTPlotSymbol`.

Note that in the black marker, the square encloses the circle, while in the red one, the circle is taller than it should be. Also, there's a stroke missing from the tip of the arrow in the red case.

Comment: I don't see any difference except that the black marker is clipped by the white rectangle while the red one isn't. As noted in my answer below, Core Plot uses a flipped coordinate system on iOS, so you'll need to adjust the drawing coordinates when creating the plot symbol path.

Comment: That's the difference, both red and black markers should be (perfect) circles. Black is, red isn't. Both are drawn with the same path with the code mentioned above.

Comment: Look closely at the image. The black circle has flat spots on the edges where it is clipped by the box. The path is too big to fit in the square. Reduce the radius slightly or make the box bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Core Plot shares drawing code between the Mac and iOS, it uses the same drawing coordinate system on both platforms where (0, 0) is the lower-left corner of the drawing canvas. This is flipped from the normal drawing coordinate system on iOS.